# Confusion over derivative (Calculus perpective )

Tags: derivatives

Have a look at this beautiful girl:

[image]

She is literally just (a dummy matrix):

[image]

Where each element represents the value of the *black-to-white* level put in each pixel at *(x,y)* location, thus the function is *f(x,y)*.

A calculus books taught me that the derivative of *f* with respect to x-axis at *(a,b)* defined as :

[image]

In a computer vision we compute the derrivates as :

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \approx \frac{f(x+1,y) - f(x,y)}{1} = f(x+1,y) - f(x,y) $$ .

They are both same formula, same principal, except that in the second formula it assumes that *h=1* , instead of *h approaches to 0*.

Why is it computed under *h=1*? I think it's a matter of interpretation that I don't get very well over the derivative?

Actually here , https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65152/derivative-for-x-direction-for-image.  It's mentioned that :

*This is because f(x,y), the pixel color values at (x,y), is a value of 1 away from the nearest neighboring pixels in both the x and y direction.*

If so, wouldn't it matter, if I use *h* about *0.00001* for example.

Comment: Computer is doing an approximation of derivative, under assumption that for small enough $h$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is close to the approximation. Computer chose $h$ because it thought it was small enough and thus gives a good approximation. But that heavily depends on function $f$ itself and I doubt $1$ would be good enough approximation for most of practical uses

Comment: Unit 1 is arbitrary...

Comment: @AbdallahHammam, I know it:), but that's not what  I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is that when the true continuous derivative is not available, you approximate it for some finite and small $h$. In the case of computer vision and computer graphics, the minimum available step size is 1 pixel on the screen...

Comment: Thanks, but don't you think that it's kind of unsual, as we don't exactly know the distance between 2 pixels, thought they are separated in constant distance.

Comment: The distance between 2 pixels is 1 pixel.

Comment: Ah I see your point , the function of the pixels is actually discrete thus continuous derivative is not applicable , so we choose the smallest possible value for an integer, the closest to 0 . Thank you very much